# How do I order this ggplot2 graph by descending order?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

```
ggplot(data = ames) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = as.factor(Neighborhood),
                         y = Gr.Liv.Area,),
                         stat = "Summary",
                         fun = "mean" ,
                         fill = "sky blue") +
  labs(title = "Overall Quality by Average Sales Price",
       x ="Neighbourhood",
       y = "Avergage living area (SqFt)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 8), 
        legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: Difficult to help without data but have you tried this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph ?

Comment: Simplest way is to `reorder` inside `geom_bar` like so: `geom_bar(aes(reorder(Neighborhood, -GrLivArea), GrLivArea), stat = "Summary", fun = "mean", fill = "sky blue")`

Comment: Check all the answers in the linked question as some are rather old now.